# reconstructing signal with tensorflow.contrib.signal causes amplification or modulation (frames, overlap_and_add, stft etc)

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, signal-processing

***UPDATE***: I've reimplemented this in librosa to compare, and the results are indeed very different to the results from tensorflow. Librosa gives the results I'd expect (but not tensorflow).

I've posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16465) on the tensorflow repo, but it's quiet there so I'm trying here. Also I'm not sure if it's a bug in tensorflow, or user error on my behalf. For completeness I'll include full source and results here too.

A.) When I create frames from a signal with `frame_length=1024` and  `frame_step=256` (i.e. 25% hop size, 75% overlap) using a hann window (also tried hamming), and then I reconstruct with `overlap_and_add`, I'd expect the signal to be reconstructed correctly (because of COLA etc). But instead it comes out exactly double the amplitude. I need to divide the resulting signal by two for it to be correct.

B.) If I use STFT to create a series of overlapping spectrograms, and then reconstruct with inverse STFT, again with `frame_length=1024` and `frame_step=256`, the signal is again reconstructed at double amplitude.

I realise why these might be the case (unity gain at 50% overlap for hann, so 75% overlap will double the signal). But is it not normal for the reconstruction function to take this into account? E.g. librosa istft does return signal with correct amplitude while tensorflow returns double.

C.) 
At any other frame_step there is severe amplitude modulation going on. See images below. This doesn't seem right at all.

**UPDATE**: If I explicitly set `window_fn=tf.contrib.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn(frame_step)` in `inverse_stft` the output is correct. So it seems the `frame_step` in `inverse_stft` is not being passed into the window function (which is also what the results hint at).

original data:

[image]

tensorflow output from frames + overlap_and_add:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

tensorflow output from stft+istft:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

librosa output from stft+istft:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

tensorflow code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
out_prefix = 'tensorflow'


def plot(data, title, do_save=True):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
    plt.plot(data[:3*frame_length])
    plt.ylim([-1, 1])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid()
    if do_save: plt.savefig(title + '.png')
    plt.show()


def reconstruct_from_frames(x, frame_length, frame_step):
    name = 'frame'
    frames_T = tf.contrib.signal.frame(x, frame_length=frame_length, frame_step=frame_step)
    windowed_frames_T = frames_T * tf.contrib.signal.hann_window(frame_length, periodic=True)
    output_T = tf.contrib.signal.overlap_and_add(windowed_frames_T, frame_step=frame_step)
    return name, output_T


def reconstruct_from_stft(x, frame_length, frame_step):
    name = 'stft'
    spectrograms_T = tf.contrib.signal.stft(x, frame_length, frame_step)
    output_T = tf.contrib.signal.inverse_stft(spectrograms_T, frame_length, frame_step)
    return name, output_T


def test(fn, input_data):
    print('-'*80)
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    input_T = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]) 
    name, output_T = fn(input_T, frame_length, frame_step)

    title = "{}.{}.{}.l{}.s{}".format(out_prefix, sample_rate, name, frame_length, frame_step)
    print(title)

    with tf.Session():
        output_data =  output_T.eval({input_T:input_data})

#    output_data /= frame_length/frame_step/2 # tensorflow needs this to normalise amp
    plot(output_data, title)
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(title+'.wav', sample_rate, output_data)


def generate_data(duration_secs, sample_rate, num_sin, min_freq=10, max_freq=500, rnd_seed=0, max_val=0):
    '''generate signal from multiple random sin waves'''
    if rnd_seed>0: random.seed(rnd_seed)
    data = np.zeros([duration_secs*sample_rate], np.float32)
    for i in range(num_sin):
        w = np.float32(np.sin(np.linspace(0, math.pi*2*random.randrange(min_freq, max_freq), num=duration_secs*sample_rate)))
        data += random.random() * w
    if max_val>0:
        data *= max_val / np.max(np.abs(data))
    return data


frame_length = 1024
sample_rate = 22050

input_data = generate_data(duration_secs=1, sample_rate=sample_rate, num_sin=1, rnd_seed=2, max_val=0.5)

title = "{}.orig".format(sample_rate)
plot(input_data, title)
scipy.io.wavfile.write(title+'.wav', sample_rate, input_data)

for frame_step in [256, 512, 768, 1024]:
    test(reconstruct_from_frames, input_data)
    test(reconstruct_from_stft, input_data)

print('done.')
```

librosa code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import librosa.core as lc
out_prefix = 'librosa'


def plot(data, title, do_save=True):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
    plt.plot(data[:3*frame_length])
    plt.ylim([-1, 1])
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid()
    if do_save: plt.savefig(title + '.png')
    plt.show()


def reconstruct_from_stft(x, frame_length, frame_step):
    name = 'stft'
    stft = lc.stft(x, n_fft=frame_length, hop_length=frame_step)
    istft = lc.istft(stft, frame_step)
    return name, istft


def test(fn, input_data):
    print('-'*80)
    name, output_data = fn(input_data, frame_length, frame_step)

    title = "{}.{}.{}.l{}.s{}".format(out_prefix, sample_rate, name, frame_length, frame_step)
    print(title)

#    output_data /= frame_length/frame_step/2 # tensorflow needs this to normalise amp
    plot(output_data, title)
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(title+'.wav', sample_rate, output_data)


def generate_data(duration_secs, sample_rate, num_sin, min_freq=10, max_freq=500, rnd_seed=0, max_val=0):
    '''generate signal from multiple random sin waves'''
    if rnd_seed>0: random.seed(rnd_seed)
    data = np.zeros([duration_secs*sample_rate], np.float32)
    for i in range(num_sin):
        w = np.float32(np.sin(np.linspace(0, math.pi*2*random.randrange(min_freq, max_freq), num=duration_secs*sample_rate)))
        data += random.random() * w
    if max_val>0:
        data *= max_val / np.max(np.abs(data))
    return data


frame_length = 1024
sample_rate = 22050

input_data = generate_data(duration_secs=1, sample_rate=sample_rate, num_sin=1, rnd_seed=2, max_val=0.5)

title = "{}.orig".format(sample_rate)
plot(input_data, title)
scipy.io.wavfile.write(title+'.wav', sample_rate, input_data)

for frame_step in [256, 512, 768, 1024]:
    test(reconstruct_from_stft, input_data)

print('done.')
```

- Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- Tensorflow installed from binary v1.4.0-19-ga52c8d9, 1.4.1
- Python 2.7.14 | Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 16 2017, 17:29:19). IPython 5.4.1
- Cuda release 8.0, V8.0.61, cuDNN 6
- Geforce GTX 970M, Driver Version: 384.111

(Just tried with TF1.5, Cuda9.0, cuDNN 7.0.5 as well, and same results).

Comment: I noticed a similar problem the first section of this programming [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.signal).  It mentions the window function must be used to get the correct amplitude in the reconstructed signal.  By the way, did you file a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tf.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn`

```
window_fn=tf.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn(frame_step)
tf_istfts=tf.signal.inverse_stft(tf_stfts, frame_length=frame_length, frame_step=frame_step, fft_length=fft_length, window_fn=window_fn)}
```

See more at [inverse_stft_window_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/inverse_stft_window_fn)

Answer (score 0):

An infinite sequence of Von Hann windows with a 50% overlap sums to a flat unity gain.  With a 25% overlap, you double the number of windows per unit time, thus double the gain.

Overlap-add fast convolution filtering is usually done with no overlap and no (non-rectangular) windowing, just sufficient zero-padding of at least the length of the impulse response of the filter function.  Any overlap percentage should not include any added zero padding length.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Two points: i) I understand that unity gain is at 50% overlap, but isn't it normal for reconstruction fn to take this into account? E.g. librosa's istft does, and that's what i'd expect. Maybe this is not the norm? ii) What about the severe amp modulation at any other hop size other than 25%? I've compared results to librosa and very different. See updated post.